# Multiplication for long fixed-point numbers

Tags: fixed-point

I want to compute the multiplication of `a*b`, where:

- `a` is an unsigned fixed-point type number with 150 word length and 70 fraction length, and
- `b` is an unsigned fixed-point type number with 54 word length and 53 fraction length.

Since I am designing for FPGA, I can only use unsigned fixed-point numbers with maximum of 128 word length. Hence, I am thinking of splitting `a` into `a_msb`, containing the 22 most significant bits of `a` and `a_lsb` containing the remaining 128 least significant bit (so `a_lsb` will be a fixed-point number of 128 word length and 70 fraction length).

I am thinking that I can perform the multiplication of `a_msb*b`, and then `a_lsb*b`, but then how would I combine them later on?

Also, what would be the best way to get the multiplication without losing too much precision, considering that I am constraint with 128-bit?

Comment: Look into *Karatsuba multiplication* for the basic technique of breaking a multiplication into smaller multiplication problems.  (There's also *Toom-Cook multiplication*, but I don't think your numbers are quite big enough for that to be worth the additional complexity over Karatsuba.)

Comment: What FPGA limits you to 128 bit integers? I have never heard of such a restriction before. And you can most certainly use signed integers.